# Simple command-line calculator

Tags: shell, calculator

#### Issue:

Every now and then I need to do simple arithmetic in a command-line environment.  E.G. given the following output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   fat32                 hidden, diag
 2      106MB   64.1GB  64.0GB  ext4
 3      64.1GB  192GB   128GB   ext4
 5      236GB   256GB   20.0GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

What's a simple way to calculate *on the command line* the size of the unallocated space between partition 3 and 5?

### What I've tried already:

### bc

```
bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
236-192
44
quit
```

where the **bold** above is all the stuff I need to type to do a simple `236-192` as `bc 1+1` echoes `File 1+1 is unavailable.`

### expr

```
expr 236 - 192
```

where I need to type **spaces** before and after the operator as `expr 1+1` just echoes `1+1`.

Comment: If you're intending to do this interactively, you don't need to type `quit` into `bc`; pressing `ctrl-D` will do, as it will in any interactive program.

Comment: `dc` is (IMO) far superior to `bc`.

Comment: I *think* the unallocated space between ptn 3 and 5 should be 236 - 192, and not 236 - 128?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma good eye!  (It was just an example and no one spotted that one!)

Comment: Do you, by "simplest", in fact mean a calculator that allows you to type the absolute least?  This is what it seems like in your comparison of `bc` and `expr`. In that case you may want an RPN calculator like `dc`.

Comment: @Kusalananda A RPN dc (`dc <<<'2 3*p'`) is not less than bc (`bc <<<'2*3'`).

Comment: @Isaac That depends on how complex your calculations are.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, RPN reduces one key-press per internal parenthesis and two per external parenthesis, but that is all. Yes, I used HP at college and found out that a RPN calculator is able to deal with most complex formulas on stride, I mean, it is usually easy to walk tru any formula using the stack. I like that, that is the strong point about RPN. But you have to agree that for **simple** math RPN actually needs more key-presses. That is exacerbated in bc where there is no need for an `equal` (`=`) key-press to get the result.

Comment: Hi, please have a look at my answer. I think it's exactly what you're looking for :) 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515196/48955

Comment: @JanM. I'm the one who upvoted....  **;-)**

Comment: I've used with some success `echo` with `bc` just by piping echo into bc using something like `echo 2048-192 | bc` which also works on shells other than bash

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/378661/any-command-line-calculator-for-ubuntu/379282

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of verbosity involved in using `bc`:

```
$ bc <<<"236-192"
44
$ bc <<<"1+1"
2
```

(assuming your shell supports that).

If you’d rather have that as a function:

```
$ c() { printf "%s\n" "$@" | bc -l; }
$ c 1+1 22/7
2
3.14285714285714285714
```

(`-l` enables the standard math library and increases the default scale to 20.)

Store the `c` definition in your favourite shell startup file if you want to make it always available.

Comment: `bc<RET>236-128<RET>quit<RET>` is 16 keystrokes. `bc<<<"236-128"<RET>` is 15 keystrokes. Not what I would call "greatly reduced amount of typing" :-) In addition, `bc` can be exited with `^D`, so first option is reduced to 13 keystrokes (counting `^D` as two).

Comment: @L.Levrel With the function it's just `c 1+1` which is just what I needed!  **:-)** (answer updated to make that clearer)

Comment: And if you do floating point :  c 'scale=2; 17/3'  (or better, have scale a variable used inside the 'c()' function, and define it's value whenever you need to have n decimal digits. default is 0.)

Comment: I find the here-string approach quite useful, since you can easily recall and edit previous calculation right from your shell history. Moreover, on bash you don't even need to add the quotes.

Answer (score 47):

## Summary

There are several solutions listed (shell, awk, dc, perl, python, etc.).

A function may be defined with any option (gawk seems to be the most flexible to use)

```
c () { local in="$(echo " $*" | sed -e 's/\[/(/g' -e 's/\]/)/g')";
       gawk -M -v PREC=201 -M 'BEGIN {printf("%.60g\n",'"${in-0}"')}' < /dev/null
     }
```

And use it like:

```
$ c 236- 192
44
```

---

#### Shell

The **simplest** calc in CLI is the CLI (shell) itself (If `IFS` is default):

```
$ echo $(( 22 + 333 ))
355
```

Spaces could be omitted:

```
$ echo $((22*333))
7326
```

As it is [part of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) **almost** all shells have it. And it includes **most** of C language math functionality (except that zsh has a different precedence, set C_PRECEDENCES to restore it to a compatible value):

```
$ echo $((22*333^2))
7324
```

And **some** shells have most of the C language math syntax (including comma):

```
$ echo $((a=22,b=333,c=a*b,c))
7326
```

But it is only integer math (and usually less than 2<sup>63</sup> in present day OSes) in some shells:

```
$ echo $((1234/3))
411

$ zsh -c 'echo $((2**63))'
-9223372036854775808
```

Some shells could do floating math:

```
$ ksh -c 'echo $((1234/3.0))'
411.333333333333333

$ ksh -c 'echo $((12345678901234567890123/3.0))'
4.11522630041152263e+21
```

Avoid zsh (zcalc has similar problems):

```
$ zsh -c 'echo $((12345678901234567890123 + 1))'
zsh:1: number truncated after 22 digits: 12345678901234567890123 + 1
-1363962815083169259
```

I recommend you to avoid `expr`, it needs weird escapes sometimes:

```
$ expr 22 \* 333
7326
```

#### bc

At the next level is ([also POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html))`bc` (cousin of RPN `dc`)

```
$ echo '22*333' | bc
7326

$ echo '22 333 * p' | dc
7326
```

The `dc` **was** (historically) used to implement bc and [got excluded from POSIX in 2017](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap04.html).

Shorter if your shell supports it:

```
$ bc <<<'22*333'
7326
```

Or even:

```
$ <<<'22*333' bc
7326
```

Both are arbitrary precision calculators with some internal math functions:

```
$ bc <<<2^200
1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376

$ echo 's(3.1415/2)' | bc -l        # sine function
.99999999892691403749
```

#### awk

After those really **basic** calc tools, you need to go up to other languages

```
$ awk "BEGIN {print (22*33)/7}"
103.714

$ perl -E "say 22*33/7"
103.714285714286

$ python3 -c "print(22*33/7)"
103.71428571428571

$ php -r 'echo 22*33/7,"\n";'
103.71428571429
```

#### function

You may define a function of any of the above options:

```
c () 
{ 
    local in="$(echo " $*" | sed -e 's/\[/(/g' -e 's/\]/)/g')";
    gawk -M -v PREC=201 -M 'BEGIN {printf("%.60g\n",'"${in-0}"')}' < /dev/null
}
```

And use:

```
$ c 22* 33 /7                   # spaces or not, it doesn't matter.
103.714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714
```

Comment: `dc` was never POSIX; this seems to be a common misconception. However, see the Rationale for `bc` in the 2001 edition of POSIX (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html#tag_20_09_18) where it says that standardizing `dc` was considered, but not done.

Also, in the link you gave, `dc` is listed as a *excluded* utility, not a *removed* utility.

Comment: Another useful tip if you define a function like c() above, is to add "alias calc=noglob c" - that will let you use the asterisk in expressions without quoting it, eg "calc 3*4". Works in zsh, maybe others.

Comment: @isaac: Thank you for the complete answer. I like the function very much! I use it all the time. Could it be that there is not possible to write `c 1 * 2`? In my console (bash) it returns an `syntax error`.

Comment: Yes, that is not possible as the '*' gets interpreted by the shell and is expanded as a `glob` to the list of all files in the present working directory. You could **quote** the `*` like this (for example): `c 1 \* 2` (note the ```\``` used). Or quote the whole string: `c '1 * 2' `. @alex

Answer (score 30):

Reading [this pages comments](https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/), I see a UNIX/Linux program called `calc` that does exactly what you want. If on Debian / Ubuntu / derivatives:

```
sudo apt-get install apcalc
```

or on Fedora Linux:

```
sudo dnf install calc
```

then you can:

```
calc 236-192
```

and if you add an alias `alias c='calc'` to your `.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` then it just becomes:

```
c 1+1
```

on the command line.

Answer (score 20):

In `zsh`:

```
$ autoload zcalc # best in  ~/.zshrc
$ zcalc
1> 1+1
2
2> ^D
$ zcalc 5+5
1> 10
2>
```

Answer (score 12):

The [`units`](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/manual/units.html#Overview) program, whilst not intended to be used as a calculator, actually works fairly well as one.

```
$ units "236-192"
    Definition: 44
$
```

*If* there are spaces in the expression, *then the expression must be quote-protected.*
It supports exponentials and deep nesting of brackets

Comment: It's versatile: `units -t -d 10 "236GB - 192GB" GB` outputs `44`,  `units -t -d 15 "236GB - 192GB" bytes` outputs  `44000000000`, *etc.*

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I like [libqalculate](https://github.com/Qalculate/libqalculate) (the command-line version of [Qalculate](https://qalculate.github.io)).

```
$ qalc
> 236-192

  236 - 192 = 44
```

While the interface is certainly simple, (lib)qalculate is a powerful, full-fledged calculator. e.g.

```
> fibonacci(133) to hex

  fibonacci(133) = approx. 0x90540BE2616C26F81F876B9

> 100!

  factorial(100) = approx. 9.3326215E157

> sin(pi)

  sin(pi * radian) = 0
```

It also does useful things like tab completion, open/close parentheses when necessary, and prints its interpretation of the query.

```
> 18-2)/4

  (18 - 2) / 4 = 4
```

To exit, I simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

For even quicker access, set it to something like `alias ca='qalc'`.

Answer (score 8):

What I do in zsh is:

```
$ <<< $(( 236 - 192 ))
44
```

In bash, I'd have to explicitly mention cat:

```
$ cat <<< $(( 236 - 192 ))
44
```

If I wanted the result to include fractional digits (works in zsh, not in bash), I'd add a radix point to one of the operands

```
$ <<< $(( 236 / 128 )) 
1
$ <<< $(( 236. / 128 ))
1.84375
```

Comment: `echo $((236 - 128))` works too ;-).

Comment: Avoid zsh: `zsh -c 'print $((12345678901234567890123 + 1))'
zsh:1: number truncated after 22 digits: 12345678901234567890123 + 1
-1363962815083169259`.

Comment: @Isaac at least zsh tells you it’s truncating; bash just gives you an incorrect answer without complaining.

Comment: @StephenKitt The problem with zsh is more complex than one output shows. Compare: `zsh -c 'print $((12345678901234567890123 + 1))'` and `zsh -c 'print $((123456789012345678901 + 1))'`.  It is truncating at different lengths and producing different numeric results.

Comment: @StephenKitt Instead Bash is following the manual (and the C language about overflow of a signed int). Not that I personally like it, but it is documented as so. Try `bash -c 'echo $((1<<63))'` and ``bash -c 'echo $(((1<<63)-1))'`.

Comment: @Isaac I’m not disputing that zsh has issues; my comment still stands. Basically avoid shells for arithmetic on large numbers ;-).

Comment: With your last comment I agree :-).

Comment: @Isaac I’m somewhat acquainted with bash’s behaviour, I wrote [this answer on the largest integer it can handle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325213/86440) ;-).

Comment: Note that zsh is diferent to all other shells in the operations precedence, try `sh -c 'echo "$((22*33^2))"'` for several shells (sh value).

Comment: @Isaac indeed, I got caught out by that in earlier versions of the linked answer.

Answer (score 8):

As remarked in a comment to an earlier reply, the standard shell (ba)sh allows to evaluate arithmetic expressions within `$((...))`. I could not double-check whether this is part of the POSIX standard, but I did check that it also works on Cygwin and the Mingw32 shell.

To *see* the result, you'd indeed have to type `echo $((...))`, which makes some characters more than (interactive use of) `bc`. However, to *use* the result in a script, this will most probably be shorter than the `bc` solution (which could be, e.g., `` `echo ...|bc` ``).

Concerning verbosity, the `bc` command allows the option `-q` which suppresses output of the *"normal GNU `bc` welcome"*.

As a final, slightly borderline remark, let's note that `bc` is not just a calculator but rather a full-fledged programming language (including user defined functions, while & for loops, etc etc). Another fact that suggests to prefer the build-in arithmetic capabilities for such simple calculations, rather than an external program. That said, extracting the data for given partition number(s) and dealing with "M", "G" suffixes, as the original question seemed to ask for, might call for `(g)awk` rather than `bc`.

Sources: https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html
 https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getting-Started.html

Comment: `$((...))` is called Arithmetic Expansion and it is part of POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04  For me the biggest drawback of this feature of a POSIX shell is that it supports only integer arithmetic :(

Answer (score 7):

Python open in another tab?

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on 
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3+3
6
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Before any of the other brilliant answers were posted, I ended up creating the script `/usr/local/bin/c` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=' '               # to be on the safe side, some shells fail to reset IFS.
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ];  then
    echo "$(basename "$0"): a (very) simple calculator."
    echo "type $(basename "$0") expression to evaluate (uses bc internally)"
fi

printf '%s\n' "$*" | bc -l  # safe for most shells
                            # we may use 'bc -l <<<"$*"` for ksh, bash, zsh
```

#### so: typing `c 1+1` yields `2`!  :-)

**Note 1:** I used `c` because that command does not exist on any Unix system that I could find.  If you would have aliased that to your c compiler, use anything else that is short and you don't use.
**Note 2:** [Source](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9891)

Comment: (1) Decided to use `echo "$*" | bc -l` as the shebang you used was `/bin/sh` and I don't know if you have ksh/bash/zsh available. (2) Note that you may change the scale to calculate is you execute `c 'scale=60;777/333', for example. Hope it helps @Fabby

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [concalc](http://extcalc-linux.sourceforge.net/concalcdoku.html)?

> Description: console calculator concalc is a calculator for the Linux
>   console. It is just the parser-algorithm of extcalc packed into a
>   simple console program. You can use it if you need a calculator in
>   your shell. concalc is also able to run scripts written in a C-like
>   programming language.

```
$ concalc 1+1
2
$ concalc sqrt2
1.41421356237309505
```

Install with:

```
sudo apt-get install concalc
```

Answer (score 4):

`dc -e '236 192-p'`

... of course, if you're not familiar with [`dc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and you require more than subtracting two numbers, you'll spend more time looking up how to use `dc` (and maybe [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) in general) than you'll save with more familiar methods.

Comment: Yeah, had a 3-minute look at Desk Calculator and knew it wasn't for me: I was a TI, not an HP student.

Answer (score 3):

If you have gradle installed then you have groovy...

If groovy is pathed correctly you should be able to use:

```
groovy -e "println 1+1"
```

This may seem a bit redundant with all the other examples, but:

- groovy is a powerful language
- possibly the best library support available
- powerful and simple math functions (Like arbitrary precision math)
- uses redirectable stdout for it's output so it is amazingly flexible (great to use inside batch files with backticks `` and the like).

If you don't have java installed it's probably not worth installing groovy & java--it's just an option if groovy is already available.

Comment: Nope, not really, but a neat idea anyway!  **:-) +1**

Answer (score 3):

Just because Python was mentioned a few times in other answers, here the generalized answer, summarizing the basic idea:

You can use many interpreted languages with a repl as your calculator. This saves you the learning curve for a "special" program, such as `bc`.

For example if you already happen to know lisp, you could use that as your quick
and dirty command line calculator:

```
sbcl --eval '(progn (print (+ 1 2 3 4)) (quit))'
```

Or Ocaml, as another example:

```
echo "let d = 553 - 226 in print_int d" | ocaml -noprompt -stdin
```

Whatever language deems you most convenient.

Answer (score 3):

**2020 answer**

Append

```
# Calc
c(){ 
  echo "scale=2; $*" | bc -l
}
```

to your `~/.aliases`, then

```
$ c 1/3
.33
```

(The original issue has been solved multiple times already. However, the title "Simple command-line calculator" may require division to some decimal points. The use of the `-l` option with `bc` seems to give 20 decimal points, which is perhaps too many for a 'simple' calculator. This answer, which frankensteins answers from @stephenKitt and @sjas was the simplest solution I found.)

Answer (score 2):

**If python is installed, you can do a lot of mathematical operation through command line. I tried to provide some example below.**

I have used `python3` you can use `python`. The difference between `python` and `python3` occur when divided(fractional) operation occur, to avoid the issue see below **python vs python3**.

> Note: Latest all linux dist comes with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 by default. In case if require to install python [click here](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Add, Subtract, Multiply & Divide:

```
$ python3 <<< "print(12+3)"
15
$ python3 <<< "print(12-3)"
9
$ python3 <<< "print(12*3)"
36
$ python3 <<< "print(12/3)"
4
```

Modulus -remainder of the division:

```
$ python3 <<< "print(14%3)"
2
```

Floor division:

```
$ python3 <<< "print(14//3)"
4
```

Exponent - x to the power of y (x^y):

```
$ python3 <<< "print(3**2)"
9
```

Square root (ex: √4 = 2):

```
$ python3 <<< "print(4**0.5)"
2
```

> **More scientific part, you will require import *math* library. Ex:**

The natural logarithm of x = log(x):

```
$ python3 <<< "import math; print(math.log(4))"
1.386294361119890e6
```

The base-10 logarithm of x = log10(x):

```
$ python3 <<< "import math; print(math.log10(10))"
1.0
```

Factorial (ex: 3! = 3.2.1 = 6):

```
$ python3 <<< "import math; print(math.factorial(3))"
6
```

Trigonometry- `sin(x)`, `cos(x)`, `tan(x)`:

```
$ python3 <<< "import math; print(math.sin(90))"
0.8939966636005579
```

Fore more math related functions [check here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html).

> **`python` Vs `python3`:**

-For divide: (use float):

```
$ python <<< "print(10.0/3)"
3.33333333333
```

-instead of

```
$ python <<< "print(10/3)"
3
```

> **Also you can use direct terminal:**

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1+3
4
>>> import math
>>> math.log10(4)
0.6020599913279624
>>> math.sqrt(4)
2.0
>>>
```

That's it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Either `bc` or `qalc`.

---

To automatically have `bc` always rounding up to two digits: (running it with `-l` is unwieldy for day to day stuff)

Edit your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias bc="BC_ENV_ARGS=<(echo "scale=2") \bc"
```

Open a new shell and run `bc` and be glad.

Answer (score 2):

Use `perl` / `python` under the hood.

The advantage?

You get the full power of all math operations

```
❯ calc 'log(e)'
1.0
❯ calc 'pi*2'
6.283185307179586
❯ calc 'pi**2'
9.869604401089358
❯ calc 'pi**pi'
36.4621596072079
```

If you stick to string inputs, you don't have to worry about glob expansions of your shell

For `zsh` or `bash` have a function something like

```
function calc {
    python3 -c "from math import *; print(eval($*))"
}
```

For `tcsh` add alias something like

```
alias   Calc            'python3 -c "from math import *; print(eval(\!*))"'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of great answers here, I actually have written a small programming language with this problem in mind, where in typing in the command line
`./Ascal 2+2`
or
`./Ascal "log(10)"`
you will immediately get the result
Final Answer:
4
for 2+2, and I'm sure you can imagine for log base 10 of 10.
Just something to keep in mind, it's also a full programming language with a bunch of useful functions built in, plotting in the console, and taking reimann sums of functions you have defined.
Check it out the project now comes with a build script so all you need to do is add it to your path variable, or add an alias in your bash config and you have an easy to use calculator!
https://github.com/andrewrubinstein/AscalLang
I'd also be really appreciative of any comments anyone interested enough to check it out might have, hope it can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo $((1+5))
6
```

This is Bash's [Arithmetic Expansion](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a one-liner:

```
$ c () { echo $(( ${1} )) }
```

Now you can use simple integer math:

```
$ c 1+1
2

$ c 25*4
100

$ c 25*4-10
90

$ c 20*5/4
25
```

Comment: This is already discussed in [Isaac’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480316/86440).

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes I upvoted Isaac's very detailed answer. I thought a one-liner summarizing some of what he posted would be helpful. The `${1}` parameter usage is unique to all answers.

Comment: I encourage you to look into the reasons other answers don’t use `${1}` ;-)