# Do math operation on the numbers typed into command line without call bc

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh, arithmetic

Sometimes I need to run some math operations. I know I can use `bc` or `echo $(( 6/2 ))`. I have created my own function for `bc` to read input. But sometimes it takes a long time to type: `_bc "6/2"`. So I have this question:

Is there way to teach zsh/bash how to run math operation for numbers in command line? One example is more than thousands words.

```
$ 6/2
$ 3.0
```

It means that zsh/bash must recognize numbers and call i.e. *bc*.

Comment: This reminds me of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/480121/86440) (which isn’t a duplicate).

Comment: While I've never seen a script called, for example, `2+2`, it could conceivably exist, in which case you'd never be able to run it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Or a bit more plausibly maybe `2/3`. You could still run it by typing something like `\2+2`, if `2+2` was parsed as an alias for `echo $((2+2))`.

Comment: Wouldn't [c 1+2+3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480121/simple-command-line-calculator) be a good alternative?  (Calculate and then you can put anything you want, no spaces needed, same commands as bc if you want)

Comment: in powershell 6/2 and simply works

Comment: @Fabby Your alternative is like use function in zsh: `_b() { printf "scale=2; %s\n" "$*" | bc; }`. It's just about name of function.

Comment: "It takes a long time to type", sounds like Emacs is for you (completion and custom key bindings are your friends). Want a (RPN) calculator? `M-x calc` Want to evaluate expression? `M-x run-python` Want to compute sin, cos, tan? `M-x run-octave` ...

Comment: @waldauf Could you explain how the answer you selected works in bash (a tag you selected from the start) ?

Comment: @IssaC: I'm sorry I switched to the ZSH in the previous time and didn't realize that chosen solution solves just ZSH not Bash that is in the tag.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> (bash)

With bash, using the readline utility, we can define a key sequence to place the word `calc` at the start and enclose the text written so far into double quotes:

```
 bind '"\ec": "\C-acalc \"\e[F\""'
```

Having executed that, you type `23 + 46 * 89` for example, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to get:

```
 calc "23 + 46 * 89"
```

Just press enter and the math will be executed by the function defined as calc, which could be as simple as, or a lot more complex:

```
 calc () { <<<"$*" bc -l; }
```

## a (+) Alias

We can define an alias:

```
alias +='calc #'
```

Which will comment the whole command line typed so far. You type:

```
 + (56 * 23 + 26) / 17
```

When you press enter, the line will be converted to `calc #(56 * 23 + 26) / 17` and the command `calc` will be called. If calc is this function:

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
 calc(){ s=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT='' history 1);   # recover last command line.
         s=${s#*[ ]};                        # remove initial spaces.
         s=${s#*[0-9]};                      # remove history line number.
         s=${s#*[ ]+};                       # remove more spaces.
         eval 'bc -l <<<"'"$s"'"';           # calculate the line.
       }
```

[ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh)

```
 calc(){ s=$(history -1 |                          # last command(s)
             sed '$!d;s/^[ \t]*[0-9]*[ \t]*+ //'); # clean it up 
                                                   # (assume one line commads)
         eval 'bc -l <<<"'"$s"'"';                 # Do the math.
       }
```

[zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) zsh doesn't allow neither a `+` alias nor a `#` character.

The value will be printed as:

```
 $ + (56 * 23 + 26) / 17
 77.29411764705882352941
```

Only a `+` is required, String is quoted (no globs), shell variables accepted:

```
 $ a=23
 $ + (56 * 23 + $a) / 17
 77.11764705882352941176
```

## a (+) Function

With some limitations, this is the closest I got to your request with a function (in bash):

```
+() { bc -l <<< "$*"; }
```

Which will work like this:

```
$ + 25+68+8/24
93.33333333333333333333
```

The problem is that the shell parsing isn't avoided and a `*` (for example) could get expanded to the list of files in the pwd.

If you write the command line without (white) spaces you will probably be ok.

Beware of writing things like `$(...)` because they will get expanded.

The safe solution is to quote the string to be evaluated:

```
$ + '45 + (58+3 * l(23))/7'
54.62949752111249272462

$ + '4 * a(1) * 2'
6.28318530717958647688
```

Which is only **two** characters shorter that your `_bc "6/2"`, but a `+` seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: @Issac Thank you for your answer. Yes, it's shorter - but it's about name of function which you choose. In my own name convention has every function underscore at the beginning of name.

Comment: @waldauf The name of the function could perfectly be named `_calc` or anything else.

Comment: @Isaac Solution with keyboard shortcut looks great! I'll try to do it for `bindkey` in ZSH. :]

Comment: @waldauf It seems a bit strange to both pick a convention that has an underscore at the beginning of all names (may require the shift key!) and complain about `_bc` taking a long time to type :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - I'm sorry if you understood my question like that. I was just curious if I can type into command line some math example and ZSH/Bash recognizes math and calculate it. That's all. Really.  :] And you're right - undrescore is not good name convention. I'll change it. ;]

Comment: `zsh` allows a `+` alias, you just need `alias -- +=value` for the `+` not to be treated as an option. Or use `aliases[+]=value`

Comment: You need to set the `interactivecomments` option on in `zsh` if you want `#` to be treated as comment leading in interactive instances. Not that you would need it there as you could handle it by wrapping the `accept-line` widget there instead.

Answer (score 9):

In `zsh`, you could do something like:

```
autoload zcalc
accept-line() {
  if [[ $BUFFER =~ '^[ (]*[+-]? *(0[xX]|.)?[[:digit:]]+[^[:alnum:]]' ]]; then
    echo
    zcalc -e $BUFFER
    print -rs -- $BUFFER
    BUFFER=
  fi
  zle .$WIDGET
}
zle -N accept-line
```

It redefines the `accept-line` widget (mapped on <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to a user-defined widget that checks if the current line starts with a number (decimal or hexadecimal) optionally prefixed with any number of `(`s, looking for a non-alnum character after that to avoid false positives for commands like `7zip` or `411toppm`.

If that matches then we pass it to `zcalc` (more useful than bc in that it can use shell variables and all of zsh math functions and number styles, but does not support arbitrary precision), add the line to history and accept an empty command.

Note that it can cause confusion if you enter a line with digits in things like:

```
cat << EOF
213 whatever
EOF
```

Or:

```
var=(
  123 456
)
```

Answer (score 6):

I use a variant of bash's [magic alias hack](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/aliases.html):

```
asis() { bc <<< "$(history 1 | perl -pe 's/^ *[0-9]+ +[^ ]+ //')"; }
alias c='asis #'
```

Then:

```
$ c 1+1
2
$ c -10 + 20 / 5
-6
$ c (-10 + 20) / 5
2
$ c 2^8 / 13
19
$ c scale=5; 2^8 / 13
19.69230
```

The magic is the fact that alias expansion happens *before* the usual command line processing, which allows us to create a command whose remaining arguments follow a comment character, that the implementing function finds with the history command.

This magic allows me to type `*`, `(`, and other characters literally. But that also means I can't use shell variables because `$` is also literal:

```
$ x=5.0
$ y=-1.2
$ z=4.7
$ c ($x + $y) > $z
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
```

I get around this by a bit of bootstrapping:

```
$ echo "x=$x; y=$y; z=$z"
x=5.0; y=-1.2; z=4.7
$ c x=5.0; y=-1.2; z=4.7; (x + y) > z
0
```

You might just be better off typing: `bc` <kbd>Enter</kbd> 1 + 1 <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Control+D</kbd>

---

As a side note, I have my default `bc` settings (like `scale`) in `$HOME/.bc` and I use `bc -l` in the alias. Your use may not require these modifications.

Comment: why are you saying that you can't use shell variables? you can! `alias c='calc #'; calc(){ eval "$(history -a /dev/stdout | sed 's/c /expr /;s/[()*/+-]/ \\& /g')"; };` then `x=33; c ($x/3)*10`. This has a great potential, thanks for the trick!

Comment: @mosvy Well, can't as written in my answer. But certainly `eval` raises this hack to all-new heights!

Comment: +1 Thanks for your idea, I implemented an alternative in my answer. Note that the value of `HISTTIMEFORMAT` needs to be cleared to avoid the time tag printed by `history`. Perl seems like too much for this little edition use.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by [Stéphane's zsh answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486339/117549), and longer than [Isaac's bash answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486346/117549) in total but shorter in operation:

```
trap '[[ $_ =~ [[:digit:]] ]] && bc -l <<< "$_"' ERR
```

This also has the side effect of showing a "No such file or directory" error each time:

```
$ foozle
-bash: foozle: command not found
$ 1+2+3
-bash: 1+2+3: command not found
6
$ 6/3
-bash: 6/3: No such file or directory
2.00000000000000000000
```

The regex could be tightened, depending on the operations you expect to perform.

This (ab)uses the bash behavior of calling the ERR trap when a given command does not exist. If the last command (in `$_`) contains a digit, then it executes `bc` on that "command".

---

Thanks to a [hint from Stéphane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486326/do-math-operation-on-the-numbers-typed-into-command-line-without-call-bc/486443?noredirect=1#comment892109_486443), here's a slightly cleaner way to achieve the result (requires bash 4.0 or later, which [introduced the functionality](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES)):

```
if ! declare -F command_not_found_handle > /dev/null
then
  command_not_found_handle() { 
    if [[ "$@" =~ [[:digit:]] ]]; then 
      bc <<< "$@"; 
    else
      printf 'bash: %s: command not found\n' "$1" >&2
      return 127
    fi
  }
else
  echo Unable to set up the handler function, sorry
fi
```

The function is called any time a command isn't found. If that command contains a digit, we throw it through `bc`; otherwise, we emit a message similar to bash's stock message and return a 127 exit code.

Comment: Caveat - the ERR trap is not inherited to subshells, so `(1+2)` would need to be `'(1+2)'`

Comment: `bash` and `zsh` have a `command-not-found-handler` hook (mispelled `handle` in `bash`) that you could also use here.

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane! I've incorporated the idea.

Comment: `command_not_found_handle` doesn't work on something like `123/456`, though. Bash doesn't seem to bother calling the hook on commands that look like pathnames. With the `ERR` trap, I think you could also use `$BASH_COMMAND` to get the full command line, and not just the last word. That would make expressions with spaces work.

Comment: Good clarification, @ilkkachu; thank you! I didn't see BASH_COMMAND getting set inside the trap, only $_.  BASH_VERSION='4.2.46(2)-release'

Comment: I like this solution, but it doesn't work on ZSH. Please, how I should modify it to run on ZSH?

Comment: A workaround using readline is possible and [seems simpler/easier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486346/265604).

Answer (score 5):

The following command lines are rather simple to type,

```
<<< 5+4 bc
<<< 6/3 bc
<<< 7*2 bc
```

and slightly more complicated with parentheses (must be quoted or escaped),

```
<<< "(5+4)*2/3" bc
<<< \(5+4\)*2/3 bc
```

Answer (score 2):

Another imperfect way of doing that in Bash would be to use the `DEBUG` trap, which runs on every command. With `extdebug` set, the trap handler can prevent the main command from running, so you don't get the "command not found" errors.

```
$ cat bash_calc.sh
shopt -s extdebug
debug_calc() {
    local re='^[ (]*-?[0-9]'
    if [[ $BASH_COMMAND =~ $re ]]; then
        echo "$BASH_COMMAND" | bc -l
        return 1
    fi
}
trap debug_calc DEBUG
$ . ./bash_calc.sh
$ 123 * 456
56088
$ 123/456
.26973684210526315789
```

The trap gets the full command line before expanding variables or filename patterns, so an unquoted `*` works. (But using shell variables in the calculation doesn't work.)

However, unquoted parenthesis still cause a syntax error, so this is not perfect either.

(I nicked the regex above from [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486339/170373).)

Comment: Running with extdebug active will make the shell quite slower, but it is a clever idea, thanks.

Comment: @Isaac, hmm, that's not good. I'll admit I'd never tested it for speed, though I wonder if it matters here if this is for interactive use. Anyway, as mentioned, this is just another imperfect idea. I originally wasn't going to post it at all, but there are other somewhat hackish Bash solutions here, too, so I think it can stay.

Answer (score 1):

What about expr?

```
$ expr 6 / 2
3
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.