# what timedate value is always greater than any timedate?

Tags: bash, date, coreutils

What timedate value is always greater than any timedate?

In a script, I want to provide an argument to variable `duration` so that the loop will run forever until I kill the process:

```
# `duration` has a value in seconds
end=$(($(date +%s) + duration))  

while true; do
    # ...
    [ $(date +%s) -ge $end ] && break
    # ...
done
```

Comment: `date --date=@9999999999999999` still works, adding one more 9 returns `date: time ‘99999999999999999’ is out of range`. YMMV.

Comment: Why not just `[ "$end" != never ] && [ "$(date +%s)" -ge "$end" ]`?

Comment: In `bash`, see also `printf -v now '%(%s)T' -1` to avoid the external `date` command invocation.

Comment: And the `$SECONDS` variable copied from ksh that tracks the elapsed time since the shell started.

Comment: Or the `$EPOCHSECONDS` variable in newer versions (copied from zsh)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you. They are all great suggestions. In the script possibly with some modification that keeps the same idea, how can I change `duration` to make `end` become `never`?

Comment: "run forever until YOU kill the process"... Isn't 100 years in the future far enough for that?  How old are you now?  And besides, if you really mean "forever" then you don't need to put a date at all -- just `while : ;do ... ;done`. I mean, it's redundant to put in a condition which you want to ensure will always fail -- there's no point to that. Might as well say `[ 0 -ge 1 ]  && break`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd change it to:

```
SECONDS=0

while true; do
    # ...
    [ "$duration" = forever ] || [ "$SECONDS" -lt "$duration" ] || break
    # ...
done
```

And set `duration=forever` without having to worry as to what the maximum number supported by `[` on the system is.

`$SECONDS` is automatically incremented every second. That feature comes from ksh and is also available in `zsh` and `bash`. Beware however that `$SECONDS` in `bash` is incremented every time the full seconds of wall clock time change, so for instance, if `SECONDS=0` is run at 12:00:00.999, it will be incremented to 1 at 12:00:01.000, so only one millisecond later.

If switching to `zsh` (which no longer has that bug) is an option, you can change it to:

```
typeset -F SECONDS=0
while true; do
    # ...
    (( SECONDS < duration )) || break
    # ...
done
```

And use `duration=inf` for the loop to run forever. That also allows fractional durations.

Answer (score 4):

[Stéphane’s approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642780/86440) is better, but if you really want to compare against some impossible-to-reach number, you could specify [Bash’s maximum value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325213/86440) in comparisons; on current Linux systems (both 32- and 64-bit), that’s:

```
end=9223372036854775807
```

This value can’t even be reached with current versions of GNU `date`, because they limit the year to 1900 + (2<sup>31</sup> - 1), so the maximum result of `date +%s` is 67768036191719999 (23:59:59 on December 31, 2147485547, UTC-12).

Comment: FWIW, `TZ=UTC0 faketime "$((1900 + 1<<31 - 1))-12-31 23:59:59" date +'%s %c'` outputs `67768036191676799 Wed 31 Dec -2147481749 23:59:59 UTC` for me.

Comment: Oh right, TZ is significant, so the maximum is 12 hours behind UTC. (I’m looking for the maximum which can be reached by having the clock move forwards.)

Comment: GNU `date` returns `date: time ‘67768036191676800’ is out of range` regardless of the timezone for me, maximum seems to be 67768036191676799. Note that you can have `UTC-23:59:59` for instance (larger offsets are allowed on some systems IIRC)

Comment: `TZ=Etc/GMT+12 date --date=@67768036191719999` works for me...

Comment: Thank you, Stephen!

Comment: @StephenKitt The actual limit is not difficult to find: read my answer.

Comment: Actually the limit is 1970 +/- plus/minus 32-bit signed int.

Comment: @Pourko in years?

Comment: @Pourko OK, I see your answer, but 2147485547 is 2^31-1 + 1900, not 1970.

Comment: @StephenKitt  Yes, the numbers are obvilusly swinging symmetrically in 32bit-signed range up and down from 1900, but how is it then the zero showing as 1970? I think I'm losing my mind.

Comment: @Pourko there are two different reference points here. Time uses the epoch as its base, which is why 0 is 1970; but `struct tm` (see `man localtime`) represents years as signed 32-bit integers (strictly speaking, `int`s) counting from 1900.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't difficult to find the maximum value valid for date. It is only 64 bits to test, anyways.

```
#!/bin/bash

start=${1:-50}
maxint=$(( (1<<63)-1 ))
usedate="date"

for ((n=start;n>=0;n--)); do
    limit=$((1<<n))
    if [[ $limit -lt 0 ]] || [[ $limit -gt $maxint ]] ; then limit=$maxint; fi

    if [[ $usedate == "date" ]]; then
    if endtime=$(date -d @"$((end | limit))" +'<<%s>>'); then
        enderror=""
    else
        enderror="error reported"
    fi
    else
    enderror=$( printf -v endtime '%(%s)T' "$((end | limit))" >/dev/null);
    fi
    
    if [ -z "$enderror" ]; then 
    end=$((end | limit))
    fi
    printf "end=%d %x\n" "$end" "$end"

done
```

The limit looks fine up to bit 54, where the result is:

```
$ ./script 54
end=36028797018963967 7fffffffffffff
```

But as soon as you try 55, the result gets longer to explain (probably a year limit of date).

```
$ ./script 55
end=67768036191691199 f0c2ab7c54e1bf
```

Testing printf (already defined in the script, change `usedate`) gives no limit all up to 63 bits (end=9223372036854775807 7fffffffffffffff).

You can test your date  to find out the exact limit on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, on my system the date can go back over 2 billion years! :-)

To find the valid ranges, I wrote this little script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
printdate () { TZ=UTC0 date -d@$1 ;}
limits () { # GOOD BAD
  local good=$1 bad=$2 mid
  while (( ( good > bad ? good - bad : bad - good ) >1 )) ;do
    (( mid = (good - bad) / 2  + bad )) # "(good+bad)/2" could overflow 
    printdate $mid >/dev/null 2>&1 && good=$mid || bad=$mid
  done
echo $good
printdate $good
}

((MAX=(1<<63)-1))
limits 0 $MAX
limits 0 -$MAX
```

```
Results:

# limits 0 $MAX
67768036191676799
Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 UTC 2147485547

# limits 0 -$MAX
-67768040609740800
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC -2147481748
```