# Handling 64-bit integers in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, arithmetic

I am trying to calculate the used bandwidth on the Ethernet interface (which is 1000 Mbit/s). To test my script, I am using the [iperf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iperf) tool to generate huge bandwidths.

The problem I am facing is when `eth0_rx1` and `eth0_rx2` gets the values which are greater than maximum 32-bit value. I am getting the difference as 0.

Somehow

```
printf 'eth0 Download rate: %s B/s\n' "$((eth0_rx2-eth0_rx1))"
```

is giving the correct value, but when tried with

```
eth0_diff=expr $eth0_rx2 - $eth0_rx1
```

I am getting the value 0.

Is there a way to handle if `rx_bytes` or `tx_bytes` are more than 32 bits?

I am not sure this is an elegant way of calculating used bandwidth. If not, please suggest other alternate way.

**Sample output:**

```
eth0_rx1 = 2134947002 \
eth0_rx2= 2159752166 \
eth0 Download rate: 24805164 B/s \
eth0_diff = 12536645 \
eth0_rx_kB = 12242 \
eth0_rx_kB_100 = 1224200 \
eth0_rx_kB_BW = 9

eth0_rx1 = 2159752166 \
eth0_rx2= 2184557522 \
eth0 Download rate: 24805356 B/s \
eth0_diff = 0 \
eth0_rx_kB = 0 \
eth0_rx_kB_100 = 0 \
eth0_rx_kB_BW = 0
```

**Script used:**

```
#!/bin/sh

eth0_rx1=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes)
while sleep 1; do
    eth0_rx2=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes)
    echo "eth0_rx1 = $eth0_rx1"
    echo "eth0_rx2= $eth0_rx2"
    printf 'eth0 Download rate: %s B/s\n' "$((eth0_rx2-eth0_rx1))"

    eth0_diff=`expr $eth0_rx2 - $eth0_rx1`
    echo "eth0_diff = $eth0_diff"

    #convert bytes to Kilo Bytes
    eth0_rx_kB=`expr $eth0_diff / 1024`
    echo "eth0_rx_kB = $eth0_rx_kB"

    #bandwidth calculation
    eth0_rx_kB=`expr $eth0_rx_kB \* 100`
    echo "eth0_rx_kB_100 = $eth0_rx_kB"
    #125000 = 1000 Mbit/s
    eth0_rx_kB=`expr $eth0_rx_kB / 125000`
    echo "eth0_rx_kB_BW = $eth0_rx_kB"

    eth0_rx1=$eth0_rx2
    eth2_rx1=$eth2_rx2
done
```

Comment: are you on a 32-bit platform? Which one?

Comment: 1) there is some confusion, `expr` is not an internal shell part, unlike `$(( ...))`  2) taking your figures my `expr` (ubuntu 20.10) give me correct values 3) does `bc` give correct values (e.g. `x=$(echo $eth0_rx2 - $eth0_rx1 | bc)` ) ?

Comment: @ilkkachu, I am running on custom Linux box of i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Archemar,I dont have bc utility on my Box, as you say is there alternate for `expr`, so that o get correct vales

Comment: @Cheppy, i686, so 32-bit indeed. What do you have as `/bin/sh` and `expr`? Busybox? If Busybox provides both, I think you should be able to configure it to use 64-bit arithmetic both for the shell and `expr`. I peeked at the code and it seems it'd be two different config settings, but didn't double check the actual configuratino.

Comment: Why is this question tagged for Bash, when `/bin/sh` is likely not Bash?  Even if it is Bash, it can behave very differently in POSIX-conformant mode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given that `printf 'eth0 Download rate: %s B/s\n' "$((eth0_rx2-eth0_rx1))"` is giving you the correct value, as long as integer arithmetic is good enough, you’ve got your answer: `$((eth0_rx2-eth0_rx1))`, *i.e.* [shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html).

Many shells, notably Bash, use [64-bit integers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325213/86440), even on 32-bit platforms.

Thus:

```sh
    eth0_diff=$((eth0_rx2 - eth0_rx1))
...
    eth0_rx_kB=$((eth0_diff / 1024))
...
    eth0_rx_kB=$((eth0_rx_kB * 100))
...
    eth0_rx_kB=$((eth0_rx_kB / 125000))
```

GNU `expr` *can* support arbitrary-precision arithmetic, [if it is built with the GNU MP library](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/expr-invocation.html#expr-invocation). In other cases it uses native integers, and apparently on your system (assuming you’re using GNU `expr`) those are 32 bits in size. Other implementations probably have similar limits.

Comment: Other shells can also support 64-bit arithmetic, not just Bash. GNU coreutils `expr` seems to use `intmax_t`, so it could easily support 64-bit too. Even if e.g. on x86-64, an `int` is still 32 bits. GNU expr also croaks on overflow, e.g. `expr 9223372036854775807 + 1` gives `expr: +: Numerical result out of range`. The one from Busybox overflows as usual. I wonder what platform and system they're running on.

Comment: Given the use of `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes`, the platform has to be Linux-based...

Comment: arithmetic expansion _is_ in POSIX, right? Apart from some operators like `**`and `+=` etc., that is. The basic stuff used here should be common. Yes, they should use `/bin/bash` if they want Bash, I was just wondering if it's needed here. Though Bash does use `intmax_t` for arithmetic, so at least that helps with not having to configure the arithmetic explicitly...

Comment: @ilkkachu, `+=` is in POSIX, it's `++`, `--` that's not.

Comment: The link doesn't say that 32bit machines use 64bit maxint, does it?

Comment: @TankOrSmash not quite; it says that bash uses `intmax_t`. On 32-bit Linux with glibc, `intmax_t` is 64 bits in length.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In addition, both postfix and prefix (`++` and `--`) operators are _described_ by the POSIX standard in [1.1.2 Concepts Derived from the ISO C Standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_02_01), **although they are not required to be implemented by the shell** according to [2.6.4 Arithmetic Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04).

Comment: @psqli, yes, that was my point in that earlier comment, you can't use `++`/`--` in a POSIX script, you have to use `+= 1`, `-= 1`

Answer (score 7):

`bash` does use 64bit integers:

```
$echo $((2**63-1))
9223372036854775807
$echo $((2**63))
-9223372036854775808
```

Comment: if so , how come my statement _eth0_diff=`expr $eth0_rx2 - $eth0_rx1`_ is giving zero for the second case

Comment: @Cheppy: You are using `expr` and not shell arithmetic but also you are using `/bin/sh` and not bash.

Answer (score 3):

The standard arbitrary-precision calculator is `dc`.  We can use this for large integer arithmetic:

```
eth0_diff=$(dc -e "$eth0_rx2 $eth0_rx1 -p")
```

You can even get `dc` to do the printing, using the `n` and `p` commands:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

netstatfile=/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes
test -r "$netstatfile"

eth0_rx1=$(cat "$netstatfile")

while sleep 1
do
    eth0_rx2=$(cat "$netstatfile")
    dc -e "$eth0_rx1[eth0_rx1 = ]np $eth0_rx2[eth0_rx2 = ]np" \
       -e 'r-[eth0_diff = ]np [Download rate: ]np 1024/[eth0_rx_kB = ]np' \
       -e '100/[eth0_rx_kB_100 = ]np 125000/[eth0_rx_kB_BW = ]np'
    eth0_rx1=$eth0_rx2
done
```

You may find the `numfmt` tool (part of GNU coreutils) useful for dividing by decimal or binary thousands.  It's capable of dealing with very large numbers (though admittedly not the strange mixture used here).

Comment: “Standard” but [no longer present in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html#tag_20_09_18) :-/