# On the maximum integer numeric value of any bash currently running\

Tags: bash

How can one reliably get the maximum integer numeric value of one's bash currently installed/running as is ?

Comment: Do you mean the integer version number, as in `bash --version`, or the maximum integer value that its maths subsystem can handle?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/1030129/432690) maybe? It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Edit the question to tell us. The maximum integer what?

Answer (score 3):

If you’re referring to the maximum integer value that bash can handle, see [Bitwise shift and the largest integer in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/325206/86440) (short answer: it’s 2<sup>63</sup>–1).

If you’re referring to the maximum pid which a shell can have, that depends on the system you’re using; on Linux, it’s capped to the value shown in `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`.